# WinInet API InternetConnect cannot resolve server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wininet

Suddenly, on my Windows 2012 server, the InternetConnect() WinINet method fails if I specify a hostname (ftp.acme.com for example).  If I use the IP (10.0.0.10) it's fine.  This has been in place for a very long time.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have opened a command prompt and FTP'd by hand to the server using the server name without a hitch.  I can ping it.  I can nslookup it.  Everything is fine but this method is failing with a error code 12007 (which lead me to believe it was a resolution issue).

The call is quite simple:

```
_hConnection = InternetConnect(_hOpen, _server, _port, _user, _pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, nFlag, 0);
```

if _server is the IP address, no problem.  If it is the server name, 12007.   Yes I've checked and checked that the server name is entered correctly.  Even hard-coded it on that line.

Again, this was working for years until just recently without any changes!

**Additional Information**:
I am able to run this fine locally on a Windows 7 machine.   It resolves and works fine.  It only has issues on the Windows 2012 machine.   I tried changing the application pool to run under my name with no differing results.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `nslookup your.host.name` in a console report?

Comment: It reports correctly.  The IP address.